# Looping and accessing array in mips

Tags: mips

I am trying to loop through an array and find the largest value(int) and then print out that value. With this code below i am getting a runtime error that says

"Exception occured at pc=0x00400034

Unaligned adress in inst/data fetch: 0x10010001

attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x80000180"

```
.globl __start
.data
purchases:  .word 5,10,15,20,25,7
.text

__start:
li $t1, 0 # the "i" variable
li $t2, 6 # amount of elements in the array
lw $t0 , purchases+0  #Read the value of the element [0] into $t0
j For_loop

print_int:
li $v0, 1 
syscall
li $v0, 10 
syscall

For_loop:
blt $t2,$t1,End_loop
lw $t4, purchases($t1)
ble $t0 , $t4, True
add $t1, $t1, 1           #Increment
j For_loop

True:
lw $t0 , purchases($t1)
add $t1, $t1, 1    #Increment
j For_loop         #loop

End_loop:
move $a0, $t0 
j print_int

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

All feedback is appreciated!

Comment: ’blt $t2,$t1,End_loop’ is suspected.  When i=6 ($t1 is "i" and $t2 is set to 6 at start), ’blt $t2,$t1,End_loop’ is not blanched to End_loop because 6 (value of $t2) is not less than 6 (value of i : $t1). On next statement, purchases(6) is accessed, but area of purchases is 0 to 5 and Purchases(6) is on .text area. This makes access violation. This problem may be solved change code to ’ble $t2,$t1,End_loop’ .

Comment: `add $t1, $t1, 1` you're reading words, so you need to increment by 4.